# sending gps data using icomsat v1.1

Tags: gps, arduino-uno

I am doing my final year project that tracks the vehicle and displays the position on google maps,am using an arduino,GPS module and icomsat v1.1 GPRS module.Am trying to send the GPS data to a web page at my local server with no success,how do i do this, pls help :

this is how am doing it:

```
    //set http param value
    GPRS.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://my_domain/gps_tracker.php?");
    GPRS.print("visor=false");
    GPRS.print("&latitude=");
    GPRS.print(latitude);
    GPRS.print("&longitude=");
    GPRS.print(longitude);
    GPRS.print("speed=");
    GPRS.print(speedOTG);
    GPRS.print("\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you need to send the url as a single line message, using: println instead of print.

And check if you're receiving or not any data on your GPRS module, or if you're not managing it right.

Comment: Hi Ivan thanks for your reply,I did that but it still can't work

Comment: Did you try first to get the output you want trough serial? If don't, try it, and then when you get the output you want, send it to your web page. This way you will find if your fault it's on your arduino code or web page data receiver/parser.

Comment: i get the data that i want to send,the problem now is that the response from the GPRS shield from the command(AT+HTTPACTION=0),returns(+HTTPACTION:0,200,0) which means that the data is sent but when i open the file in the server that i want to store the data it's still empty

Comment: Well, in this case, if data it's sent, then you need to check your data parser on your server. I don't know how you are receiving this data and parsing it, but maybe you're waiting for a character that's never sent,, or something like.

I don't not so much about web services but will be helpful if you post some of the code you're using to receive data.

Comment: thanks a lot for trying to help Ivan:Here is my php code am using to receive data:

Comment: pls find the code in the original question i have uploaded it there

Comment: Hi Ivan thanks a lot for your support...I finally figured it out...the icomsat v1.1 GSM shield was not able to send the data to a localhost,when i changed my server and done a little change to my php codes it now works...am glad u were there to pin point some clues,thanks again for your time